# Dell printer goes offline after second print job

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell, printer, print-server

Dell printer goes offline(server connection) after second print job. Although the printer's display says it is ready. If you turn off then on the printer you can send one job and goes back offline(server connection) on the next print job.

We have multiple Dell 2330dn printers installed through a print server, only one of the printers is experiencing this problem. 
Two different users.
Two different machines.
Two different operating systems (win7 and Vista).

The computers have been reset.
Dell printers have web interface if this helps (through IP address).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell 2330dn

Restarting the printer's local/internal print server did the trick.

Open the printer's Web interface

goto:
1. Settings (Leftside menu)
2. Network/Ports
3. Reset Print Server

Answer (score 0):

I found that having different SNMP read communities on the Windows print server (under port settings) and in the printer's web interface caused the issue.